# Getting authentication whenever I try to execute bq using python in cloud shell

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, command-line-interface

I'm trying to write a simple bq command using python and while running for the first time the cloud shell is asking authentication permission. I want to pass through that how can it be done
`

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
from google.cloud.exceptions import NotFound
from google.cloud import bigquery
from google.oauth2 import service_account
```

```
client = bigquery.Client()
client = bigqyery.Clinet.from_service_account_file('file.json')

project_id = 'esoteric-portal-365109'

query_job = """
    SELECT * FROM `esoteric-portal-365109.dataset1.students` WHERE DATE(_PARTITIONTIME) = "2022-11-03" LIMIT 100
"""
result = client.query(query_job)

print(result)
```

```
`


It should not ask for authentication in CLI for the first time when running it.
```

Comment: Do you have a typo there on line #2 for - `bigqyery.Clinet`? Is it supposed to be `bigquery.Client`?

Comment: that is a spelling mistake it is bigquery.Clinet()

Comment: Can you follow this example for authentication using service account key file?
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/authentication/service-account-file#python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior is due to [ADC](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication#adc). `ADC` is a strategy used by Cloud Client Libraries and [Google API Client Libraries](https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/client-libraries-explained) to automatically find credentials based on the application environment, and use those credentials to authenticate to Google Cloud APIs.

[gcloud auth application-default login](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/application-default/login) command is used to discover the credential.This command is useful when you are developing code that would normally use a service account but need to run the code in a local development environment where it's easier to provide user credentials. The credentials will apply to all API calls that make use of the Application Default Credentials client library.  But this method is discouraged because your user credentials may be visible to others with access to your machine.

So I recommend you to create a Service Account with a minimal set of IAM roles/permissions that your code needs and run `export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/path/to/key.json` in terminal, SDK-based code will use these automatically.